# Copiar con Buscar y reemplazar en Visual Studio Code

Tags: html, visual-studio

Resulta que tengo un código HTML del que quiero extraer todos los enlaces a imágenes que contiene. A través de "buscar y reemplazar" con el comando "src="(.*?).jpg" consigo que se "seleccionen" todos los enlaces que quiero. Ahora, mi duda es, ¿cómo pudeo hacer para seleccionar y copiar todo lo que me ha "seleccionado" buscar y reemplazar? Ya que si le doy a copiar directamente sólo me copia una línea de código.

Gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Vale acabo de encontrar la respuesta: <kbd>CRTL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.